# PHP Formemail Not showing phone or email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am having problems with PHP Formemail again with a different site.

So whenever I post a test form, I fill out every field, but I only get the name, interests and message back. The email is supposed to show both in the email with the rest of the fields and as the sender, it shows up as neither and the phone doesn't show up either. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$adminemail = 'info@info.com';

$controlvars = ' thankspage submitter ccsubmitter messagetosubmitter ';
$messagetoadmin = $_POST['Name'] ." has sent you the following message:


";

 else $messagetosubmitter = $_POST['messagetosubmitter'];

while(list($key, $value) = each($_POST))
{
 if (!stristr($controlvars, ' '. $key .' '))
 {
  $messagetoadmin .= $key .': '. $value .'

';
  $messagetosubmitter .= $key .': '. $value .'

';
 }
} 
$submitter = $_POST['Email'];
if ($submitter == '') $submitter = 'anon@anon.com';
if (strstr($submitter, "\n") || strlen($submitter) > 50) die("Begone, foul spammer.");


mail($adminemail, 'Message from site: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']),     stripslashes($messagetoadmin), 'From: '. $submitter);

if ($_POST['ccsubmitter'] == 'yes')
{
 mail($Email, 'Message from site: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']),     stripslashes($messagetosubmitter), 'From: '. $adminemail);
}
if ($autoresponse != '')
{
 $body = geturl($autoresponse);
 mail($Email, 'Re: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($body), 'From: '.     $adminemail);
}
header('Location: '. $_POST['thankspage']);
// just in case redirect doesn't work
die('<meta http-eqiv="refresh" content="0;url='. $_POST['thankspage'] .'">');

if (!function_exists('geturl'))
{
function geturl($url)
{
 if (extension_loaded('curl')) 
 {
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.02; PHP)';
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);  // timeout after 5 seconds
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);  // timeout after 5 seconds   
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
   $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
   curl_close ($ch); 
// curl_error($ch); // for debugging
   return $result;  
 }

 if (version_compare("4.3.0", phpversion(), "<"))
 { 
  $filecontents = @file_get_contents($url);
 }
 else
 {
  $fd = @fopen($url, 'rb');
  $filecontents = "";
  do 
  {
   $data = @fread($fd, 8192);
   if (strlen($data) == 0) 
   {
    break;
   }
   $filecontents .= $data;
  } while(true); 
  @fclose ($fd);
 }
 return $filecontents;
}
}

?>
```

And here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form name="Contact" id="Contact" method="post" action="formemail.php"     onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
            <input type="hidden" name="thankspage"     value="thankyou.html">
                <input type="hidden" name="ccsubmitter"     value="yes">

                <label><span>Name: *</span>
                    <input name="Name" type="text" >
                </label>
                <label><span>Email: *</span>
                    <input name-"Email" type="text" >
                </label>
                <label><span>Phone:</span>
                    <input name-"Phone" type="text" >
                </label>
                <label><span>Interests:</span>
                    <input name="interests" type="text" >
                </label>
                <label><span>Message:</span></label>
                    <label><textarea name="message"      cols="30"     rows="10" ></textarea>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated and forever remembered. Thank you in advance for your wonderful kindness!

ETA: I tried adding id= and value= to the HTML form fields, but that did absolutely nothing. It still only returned the name, interests and message and the email showed it was from anon@anon.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show because it has been written as `<input name-"Email" type="text">` instead of `<input name="Email" type="text">`. As a suggestion, why don't you write it as `<input type="email" name="Email">`?

Comment: Ahahahahahaha! Oh.my.goodness!!! I cannot believe that I missed that! I didn't notice that AT ALL. I have been looking at this code and looking at this code and trying to figure out what is wrong with it and it is a silly mistake that was just completely invisible to me.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I feel very silly but relieved that it was something as simple as that. You are in my heart forever, now.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help to you, and... it's ok... that's why it's always useful to have someone check your code once in a while. We tend to blind ourselves and think our code is 'perfect'. Happens everytime :P

Comment: It's true, sometimes a pair of fresh eyes can see things that stale eyes can't. This is one of the many reasons that this site is so valuable. Thanks again. I have no idea how long it would have taken me to realize that since I had stared at it for hours and it never showed itself to me. Hahaha. Probably days? Weeks maybe? Thank goodness for Julio!